# I tried to use Timestamp in REST services but i only see nanos

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, rest, timestamp

I want to see the complete date but when i see on Test Restfull web services i only see nanos in the date field

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <admin>
       <email>juan@gmail.vom</email>
       <fullName>Juan</fullName>
       <id>1</id>
       <lastAccess>
           <nanos>0</nanos>
       </lastAccess>
       <lastPasswordChange>
           <nanos>0</nanos>
       </lastPasswordChange>
       <login>juan</login>
       <password>12345678A</password>
       <privilege>ADMIN</privilege>
       <status>ENABLED</status>
       <adminDate>
           <nanos>0</nanos>
       </adminDate>
   </admin>
```

I don't know why this happend, I do a Test before that using util.Date and using the tag @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) and this works, but i tought that i can use directly the timestamp.
I want to see the complete date using just the Timestamp.
 This is my java class Admin

```
/**
 * Extends of class User for users that are going to control the platform
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "admin", schema = "team6dbreto2")
@XmlRootElement
public class Admin extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * A timestamp with the date of one user become admin
     */
    @NotNull
    private Timestamp adminDate;

    public Timestamp getAdminDate() {
        return adminDate;
    }

    public void setAdminDate(Timestamp adminDate) {
        this.adminDate = adminDate;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you map any class from `java.time`? Like `ZonedDateTime` preferably?

Comment: @deHaar yes i can use java classes, but i want to know how i can see the date only using timestamp, with java.util.Date with the Temporal mark works anyway. If i can't find any solution i'm going to use Date